# Existence/examples of a non measurable function measurable on its support

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a function $h:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that is Lebesgue measurable on its support, that is, $\{x\in X:h(x)\neq0\}$ but that's not Lebesgue measurable?

I don't think constructing some indicator function on a non measurable set $V\subset X$ would work, because even the complement of a non measurable subset in a measurable set can be non measurable (I think).

If it matters, the question I saw about this had $X=[0,1]$.

Comment: I do not understand your reason that an indicator function will not work.  Say $A$ is a nonmeasurable set, $h=1$ on $A$ and $h=0$ on the complement.  Then $h$ is a nonmeasurable function, but on its support $h$ is the constant $1$.

Comment: If $h(x)=0$ for $x\in V$ a non measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and $h(x)=1$ for $x\in[0,1]\backslash V$, then $h^{-1}(B)$ for some Borel set $B$ that does not include $0$ but includes $1$ wouldn't $h^{-1}(B)$ be non measurable?

Comment: What do you mean by "$h$ is measurable on its support"?  If you mean what you put in that comment, then of course $h$ measurable on its support would imply $h$ measurable.

Comment: I'll post the whole question because maybe I'm not understanding it correctly: "give an example of a function $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the support $\{x\in[0,1]:h(x)\neq 0\}$ of $h$ is a measurable set but $h$ is not a measurable function."

Comment: @AstlyDichrar You should post the question exactly as it was given.

Comment: The new version is easy.  Let $h=1$ on a nonmeasurable set, and $h=2$ on the complement.  The support is all of $[0,1]$, therefore measurable.  But of course $h$ is not measurable.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I always think using values other than $0$ and $1$ on analysis questions is forbidden.